# Graph differences between groups in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

For an example dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", 
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", 
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", 
"v", "w", "x", "y", "z"), amount = c(5.5, 5.4, 5.2, 5.3, 5.1, 
5.1, 5, 5, 4.9, 4.5, 6, 5.9, 5.7, 5.4, 5.3, 5.1, 5.6, 5.4, 5.3, 
5.6, 4.6, 4.2, 4.5, 4.2, 4, 3.8, 6, 5.8, 5.7, 5.6, 5.3, 5.6, 
5.4, 5.5, 5.4, 5.1, 9, 8.8, 8.6, 8.4, 8.2, 8, 7.8, 7.6, 7.4, 
7.2, 6, 5.75, 5.5, 5.25, 5, 4.75, 10, 8.9, 7.8, 6.7, 5.6, 4.5, 
3.4, 2.3, 1.2, 0.1, 6, 5.8, 5.7, 5.6, 5.5, 5.5, 5.4, 5.6, 5.8, 
5.1, 6, 5.5, 5.4, 5.3, 5.2, 5.1), decile = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), time = c(2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L)), .Names = c("name", "amount", 
"decile", "time"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-78L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), amount = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), decile = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), time = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("name", "amount", "decile", "time"
)), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

I want to calculate the mean difference between deciles 1 and 10 AND between 5 and 10 BY YEAR (both differences can be added to the same graph and used as a key).

So, time would be on the x axes and amount different would be on the y axes.

I would ordinarily calculate these separately and then graph the results but I'm sure R could do it as one step.  Any ideas?

Previously, I have used the following code to graph the mean (of amount) - how can I tweak it so it does the difference instead?

```
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = decile, y = amount, col = factor(time))) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y = mean, size=1) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name="Year",
                        breaks=c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                        labels=c("2014 - 2015", "2015 - 2016", "2016 - 2017", "2017 - 2018"))

p
```

Comment: So you don't use column `name` (a, b, c, etc) at all?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to get. Could you either sketch what you want the plot to look like, or at least make a dummy dataset of the output you want to plot?

Comment: Thanks @camille I want to average all the amounts for decile 1 for  2016 and do the same for decile 10 for 2016 - and then plot the difference (decile 1 average for 2016 away from decile 10 average for 2016). I then want to repeat this (on the same graph) for all the other years.  The df1 dataframe is a dummy dataframe which I created to help.

Comment: Thanks @Tung - graphs are still quite new to me... how would I use name (a, b, c, d)